# Output buffering incorrects further code

Tags: php, output-buffering

Currently I have a dynamic CSS file, completed by PHP from results in the database. At the moment I'm converting the dynamic files into static files using output buffering. The conversion to a static file works like a charm but the action is called from a jQuery dialogwindow. After the operation is completed a small piece of HTML is printed to close the dialogform.

In here lies the problem. The HTML code gets printed instead of parsed. I believe it's because of the output buffrering. When I comment the buffering code everything works again.

Can someone tell me what's going wrong?

The code in the OB im using is:

```
ob_start();
$MC_ParseTemplateCall = 1;  # is used in the include to set some values         
require_once($Template); # Template contains the path and filename
$templateCss = ob_get_contents(); #using this to store it with fopen, fwrite & fclose
ob_end_clean();
```

#### Additional info:

From a file like save.php (which is executed in a jQuery dialog)

```
<?php
    // stuff to save template related settings happens above

    # Make a static CSS file
    ParseAndStoreTemplate(DIR_PATH_TO_ROOT."../website/Templates/MyTpl2011/CSS/MyTpl2011.php");
?>
<html>
    <body onLoad="window.parent.CloseDialog();"></body>
</html>
```

Function to store the template:

```
function ParseAndStoreTemplate($Template)
{
    if(is_file($Template))
    {
        ob_start();
        $MC_ParseTemplateCall = 1;              
        require_once($Template);
        $templateCss = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $fileName   = end(explode("/", $Template));
        $templateName   = reset(explode(".php", $fileName));
        $websitePath    = DIR_PATH_TO_ROOT."../Global/Files/Website/".$GLOBALS["WebsiteId"]."/";
        $templateFolder = "CSS";

        if(!is_dir($websitePath.$templateFolder))
            mkdir($websitePath.$templateFolder);

        file_put_contents(  
            $websitePath.$templateFolder."/".$templateName,
            $templateCss);
    }
    else
        die("<strong>Opgegeven templatebestand bestaat niet</strong>: ".$Template);
}
```

Comment: When you say `After the operation is completed a small piece of HTML is printed to close the dialogform` what do you mean? Where is it printed?

Comment: The HTML code gets printed from a PHP file (like an injection). Its nothing more than `<html><body onload="window.parent.CloseDialog();"></body></html>`. But instead of that piece of code being parsed, it's printed (like <pre>, except there are no <pre>'s ;))

Comment: yes but how are you sending that to teh browser when you are generating a CSS file? surely what you are outputing here is a CSS file, so any HTML will a) not be parsed and b) probably break your CSS.

Comment: I'll post some more code tomorrow to explain the situation. I believe the code is seperated correct but the buffer doesn't get closed properly.

Comment: Additional source and info added.

Comment: ...and which browser is printing the HTML? I must admit I don't understand why that would be... but equally I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this. Is this loaded directly in the window or an Iframe, or are you calling it through AJAX? As a side note, these lines: `$fileName = end(explode("/", $Template)); $templateName = reset(explode(".php", $fileName));` can be replaced with this one: [`$templateName = basename($Template,'.php');`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out already. It seemed that the Content-Type header gets changed during output buffering. After telling the browser it should behave like a text/html page the dialog gets closed again like it should. Thanks anyway!